# Heroku Metrics - Memory Usage

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, cloud

I am using Heroku for hosting my Java Spring Boot backend and I noticed some wierd behaviour iny my metrics.

I am not sure, if I understood right, but "Memory usage" metric basically shows overall memory usage of my project, am I right? (According to documentation)

I also enabled some JVM metrcis (heap memory usage an so on)

The problem here is that even when I restart my dyno, overall memory usage will raise even if I do nothing with my app. Metrics from JVM shows heap taking only small fraction of the memory, but overall is used from 75% and I have no idea why there is such a big percentage.

When I ran my application for the first time, it started on 50% and now it is weird that is does not release some memory even if heap is cleaned by GC.

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong or how to fix it?

Thanks.

[image: Heroku metrics]